# How do you look up what lexical set a word belongs to?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, vowels

(I mean [phonological lexical sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set#Wells_Standard_Lexical_Sets_for_UK_and_U.S._English), if that wasn't clear.)

How do you look up what lexical set a word is in? Is there any sort of open database anywhere?

Like, say I have the LOT/CLOTH merger, and I want to know group the word "long" is in.

Apparently it's "CLOTH" according to that wikipedia page, but they have only three words listed for every group, with no mention of how to verify the information if you don't happen to have a speaker of that dialect handy.

Comment: Please see also [linguistics.se]

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Post should be closed.

Comment: @rogermue What do you mean, "unclear"? It's directed at readers who are already familiar with Wells' lexical sets. (And shouldn't that be common knowledge in this sub-stackexchange?) Are you speaking from that position, and still believe it's unclear?

Comment: To be honest, I have never heard of Well's lexical sets. -- As I see from the Internet this is phonetis and you should ask this in linguistics.

Comment: @rogermue I'm confused now. What *is* the subject material of the "English" stackexchange, if not linguistics specifically focused on English? >:?

Comment: Phonological lexical sets are essentially sets attempting to list phonemes, not words. The usual pronunciation/s of a given word is/are given by any decent dictionary. You may have to make your own list of 'words containing the eɪ sound' etc. Asking for resources is off-topic on ELU.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's either a request for resources or unclear.

Comment: The sound of the syllable's vowel (in the chosen dialect) is the index by which one would identify the lexical set to which it belongs. So, if you don't know how to pronounce the vowel, good luck. Does *fool* belong to the "foot" set?  You would have to consult some pronunciation authority, find the IPA representation of the vowel, and scan the appropriate column on the Well's chart.

Comment: Right. When a phonological merger has progressed far enough, those it's affected rarely can tell which words used to have which vowel. This is true with USAns trying to pronounce words with /ɑː/ and /ɒ/ in RP , and it's true with those Americans (nearly a majority, most W of the Mississippi) who merge /ɔ/ and /a/ (_Dawn_ = _Don_ ). When you can't hear it, you can't remember, identify, or reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Wikipedia [entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set#Wells_Standard_Lexical_Sets_for_UK_and_U.S._English) on lexical sets (specifically, Wells's), "long" is in the CLOTH lexical set, but not the LOT lexical set -- as you say.

The way you would find out if some other word was in this or that lexical set would be to look up its US and UK pronunciations.  [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/) will give you US and UK pronunciations both as audio and in phonetic symbols.  For example, if you look up "dog," you'll find by its phonetic representation that "dog" is in the LOT group.  There will no doubt be slight variations in the phonetic representation (Cambridge puts a : after the a in US "da:g"), and of course not everyone in a country pronounces all words the same way.  It's not an exact science -- but this looks good enough to me.

Comment: You should add that you may need to use ***two*** dictionaries to determine which lexical set it's in. LOT is /ɑ/ in AmE and /ɒ/ in BrE. CLOTH is /ɔ/ in AmE and /ɒ/ in BrE. THOUGHT is /ɔ/ in AmE and /ɔː/ in BrE. So one dictionary is not enough to tell you that *long* is in the CLOTH lexical set.

Comment: There is if the dictionary gives you both US & UK pronunciations; see above.  (But, yes, you need both.)